# Why do some core functions get wp_ while others do not? What's the rule?

Tags: core

Is there some guideline or rationale behind why some WP code functions are prefixed with `wp_` ? eg: `wp_insert_post()` vs. `update_post_meta()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This makes not that impressive answer, but - **none**.

`get_` is suffix usually means function returns something, `the_` that function echoes something.

`wp_` doesn't carry technical meaning and inconsistency in naming is from many developers participating and lack of movement to unify (moving forward is considered more important than major cleanups of older stuff to make it neat).

Comment: I (somewhat) understand the reasoning for not remedying the current situation; however, I am puzzled by the lack of defining some point in time from which, henceforth, a defined function nomenclature would be enforced. Wishful thinking, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks Rarst. Otto confirmed it. Sigh. I was hoping... I'm with Chip!

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress was and is written by a lot of different people. Patches are discussed inside wordpress trac and whoever submits or assigns to a trac ticket can post patches. If the patch gets accepted and moved into core of an upcoming version it's simply in there. So sometimes functions, vars, etc. gets the prefix while other times they don't. It relies on the participating developers.

Answer (score 2):

The `wp_` prefix is usually added to avoid naming conflicts with:

- native PHP functions, such as get_current_user()
- older/deprecated WP functions, such as get_archives()
- third-party libraries?

Answer (score 1):

I always assumed the distinction was that - beyond the basic template tags, which generally just have the simplest descriptive name possible:

1. functions that begin with `wp_` are generally high-level public API functions, which are pretty much guaranteed to always be around and retain forwards-compatability.
2. functions without that prefix are internals, stuff you shouldn't muck around with unless you know what you're doing.

I don't know if this was ever intentional, though. And like the other two answers have said, it doesn't hold up consistently. Your example of `update_post_meta` is a perfect example of something that seems like it should should have a `wp_` prefix if my classification held true. But there's enough deep legacy code in WordPress to throw off any attempt at making sense of any naming convention.

Comment: haha. I actually thought it was exactly the opposite - that wp_ functions were more of the internal (you-can-use-it-but-it's-really-internal) variety while the others were more public. Sad as it sounds though, maybe Rarst et al. are right and there is no rationale.

Comment: For the record the really internal functions start with underscore alone `_*` But there aren't that many of those and in practice they aren't that absolutely internal-only either.